# Having trouble compiling java program, no class files being generated

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I am trying to compile my java program.

here is the command i use:

```
javac -g -cp <path to jar libs folder> -sourcepath src/ -d <path to output folder> @sourceFilesList.txt
```

contents of sourceFilesList.txt is:

```
src/<package>/class1.java
src/<package>/class2.java
...
```

I get no errors when I run this command but the class files are not found in the output folder or anywhere else. I have read that this can happen when you compile empty files but I'm fairly certain that my compiler can see these files because it will give syntax errors if i for example remove a semicolon.

Comment: if you omit `-d` and the output dir, do the classes get generated in the default location (same dir as the `.java` file)?

Comment: No I dont get anything.